# how group by having limit works

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

Can someone explain how construction group by + having + limit exactly work? MySQL query:

```
    SELECT
        id,
        avg(sal)
    FROM
        StreamData 
    WHERE
        ...
    GROUP BY
        id 
    HAVING
        avg(sal)>=10.0 
        AND avg(sal)<=50.0   
    LIMIT 100
```

Query without limit and having clauses executes for 7 seconds, with limit - instantly if condition covers a large amount of data or ~7 seconds otherwise.
Documentation says that limit executes after having which after group by, this means that query should always execute for ~7 seconds. Please help to figure out what is limited by LIMIT clause.

Comment: Not sure about cache in MySQL, but in Oracle, I observed that if you run the same query more than once, the second execution takes less time. So if limit just add `top 100` after the query execution; you can try running query with `limit` first and then without it and compare?

Comment: Not related to your question, but whenever you run a `top n` query without an order by clause you are getting random records.  That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Functionally limit goes last, but a good compiler will implement a plan that applies limiting earlier in the pipeline if it can to improve performance.

Answer (score 3):

Using `LIMIT 100` simply tells MySQL to return only the first 100 records from your result set.  Assuming that you are measuring the query time as the round trip from Java, then one component of the query time is the network time needed to move the result set from MySQL across the network.  This can take a considerable time for a large result set, and using `LIMIT 100` should reduce this time to zero or near zero.

Answer (score 3):

Things are logically applied in a certain pipeline in SQL:

1. Table expressions are generated and executed (`FROM`, `JOIN`)
2. Rows filtered (`WHERE`)
3. Projections and aggregations applied (column list, aggregates, `GROUP BY`)
4. Aggregations filtered (`HAVING`)
5. Results limited (`LIMIT`, `OFFSET`)

Now these may be composed into a different execution order by the planner if that is safe but you always get the proper data out if you think through them in this order.

So group by groups, then these are filtered with having, then the results of that are truncated.

Comment: I have 10M rows of data, query only with group by and having takes seconds when query with limit executes instantly, how to explain this fact knowing that limit is running the latest.

Comment: "Now these may be composed into a different execution order by the planner if that is safe but you always get the proper data out if you think through them in this order."  Limit isn't always physically run latest.  But it always logically runs latest.

Comment: Ordinarily you will be doing group by, order by, and limit if it is faster because then you have an ability to do a limited index scan :-)

Answer (score 1):

> As soon as MySQL has sent the required number of rows to the client,
>   it aborts the query unless you are using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. The
>   number of rows can then be retrieved with SELECT FOUND_ROWS(). See
>   Section 13.14, “Information Functions”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

This effectively means that if your table has a rather hefty number of rows, the server doesn't need to look at all of them. It can stop as soon as it has found a 100 because it knows that's all that you need.